# Access from front end to backend block by CORS policy

Tags: javascript, java, html, css, spring-boot

Hi so im new to programming. i have been done a project with 1 guys and i got 1 error after i trying to check if verify otp is correct. the front end i use is(html, css, js) and backend (java, spring boot)

here is the backend code

```
   @RestController
    @RequestMapping("/api/users")
    @CrossOrigin(origins = "*",maxAge = 3600)
    public class UserController {
    
        @Autowired
        private UserService userService;
    
    @PatchMapping("/verify")
        @Operation(summary = "Customer enters OTP code", description = "Check if OTP information is correct, if correct, enable it so the customer can log in")
        public ResponseEntity<?>authtotp(@RequestParam(name = "otp") String otp) {
            userService.verifyAccount(otp);
            return ResponseEntity.ok().build();
        }

 

    public CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
            CorsConfiguration config = new CorsConfiguration().applyPermitDefaultValues();
    
            UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource cors = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
           

 cors.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", config);

        return cors;
    }
```

front end

```
    function verifyOtp() {
    const otp1 = document.getElementById("opt1").value;
    const otp2 = document.getElementById("opt2").value;
    const otp3 = document.getElementById("opt3").value;
    const otp4 = document.getElementById("opt4").value;
    const otp5 = document.getElementById("opt5").value;
    const otp = otp1 + otp2 + otp3 + otp4 + otp5;
    
    axios.patch("http://localhost:8080/api/users/verify", { otp: otp })
        .then(response => {
            document.getElementById("verification-message").innerText = "Account verified successfully";
            document.getElementById("verification-message").style.color = "green";
            setTimeout(() => {
                window.location.href = "login.html";
            }, 3000);
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.error("Error verifying OTP:", error.response.data.error);
            document.getElementById("verification-message").innerText = "Wrong OTP CODE!!";
            document.getElementById("verification-message").style.color = "red";
        });
}

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
    document.querySelector("button").addEventListener("click", function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        verifyOtp();
    });
});
```

when i enter the otp on front end in console its said this.

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8080/api/users/verify' from origin 'http://127.0.0.1:5500' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
xhr.js:258 
        
        
       PATCH http://localhost:8080/api/users/verify net::ERR_FAILED
(anonymous) @ xhr.js:258
xhr @ xhr.js:49
qe @ dispatchRequest.js:51
value @ Axios.js:170
(anonymous) @ Axios.js:40
f @ axios.min.js:1
(anonymous) @ axios.min.js:1
(anonymous) @ axios.min.js:1
o @ axios.min.js:1
s @ Axios.js:38
(anonymous) @ Axios.js:38
n @ Axios.js:38
s.value @ Axios.js:60
(anonymous) @ Axios.js:209
(anonymous) @ bind.js:5
verifyOtp @ verifyaccount.js:37
(anonymous) @ verifyaccount.js:55
verifyaccount.js:46 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'data')
    at verifyaccount.js:46:66
```

here is the public Configuration

Comment: `Response to preflight` - where does your *server* handle CORS preflight (OPTIONS) request?

Comment: public CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
        CorsConfiguration config = new CorsConfiguration().applyPermitDefaultValues();

        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource cors = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        cors.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", config);

        return cors;
    }
this one?

Comment: a) can't read that, and b) does it handle CORS preflight? I mean, you're using it, surely you've read the relevant *documentation* on how to use it

Comment: so im not the guys that write the back end code and he said that it should have. but i still get this error and i thought using spring boot it should automatically configures CORS handling for you?

Comment: well, clearly the guys that write the back end code don't know how CORS works - why would anything automatically allow CORS? CORS is a decision to allow certain web pages access to ones own resources.

Comment: okay, thanks for helping im gonna said back to him and he gonna check it again =D